# Как сделать так, чтобы если в списке стоят 3 одинаковых числа под ряд то они удалялись?

Tags: python

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 9]
```

Как сделать так, чтобы если в списке стоят от 3 одинаковых числа подряд то они удалялись? И нужно еще записать сколько элементов было удалено. Желательно, чтобы метод был без применения [pip](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/).
Я не могу составить алгоритм действий, помогите мне его пожалуйста составить. Я пытался составить алгоритм, но я не смог его составить в силу знания  Python

Comment: __Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос.__ Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и __укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности__ при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: MaxU Спасибо за подсказку, я новичок и мало что тут понимаю 

Comment: @ПИТОНИСТверсия-3-8 без pip-a - значит без НЕдефолтных библиотек. Т. е. чистый Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Первый раз (ваш первый вопрос) - прощается, второй раз - запрещается*. Ответ, так и быть, дам (*хотя и не должен*), **НО**:

### ЧИТАЙТЕ АЛГОРИТМ И СМОТРИТЕ ССЫЛКИ!

Итак, вот Ваш код:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 9]
s=0
for i in range(len(a) - 3, 0, -1):
    if a[i:i+3] ==  [a[i]] * 3: del a[i:i+3]; s+=3 
print(f'Остался список {a}, удалено {s} символов.')
```

### Алгоритм:

В третьей строке мы используем цикл [`for`](https://pythonchik.ru/osnovy/cikl-for-v-python) для *перебора* элементов списка `a`.

Если встречаются 3 элемента подряд, то [удаляем](https://tirinox.ru/python-all-about-del/) их и увеличиваем счётчик на 3.

Затем печатаем фразу со списком `a` и переменной-счётчиком `s`.

Comment: Вам помог ответ?

Comment: Спасибо, такой краткий и понятный код! Огромное спасибо! Сори что долго не отвечал, я был занят и даже не включал пк

Comment: У меня возник такой вопрос. Если у меня в списке стоит больше 9 одинаковых чисел, то все 9 одинаковых чисел удаляются а другие нет. Я пробовал изменить это в for i in range(len(a) - 3, 0, -1): поставив не -3 а >3. Но так не работает...

Answer (score -1):

```
List = [1,1,3,4,6,6,3,5,1] #тестовый список
x = 0 #переменная для количества удаленных элементов
try : #если будет меньше 3-х эл-тов то будет ошибка
    for i in range(len(List)) : # цикл
        if List[i - 2] == List[i] == List[i - 1] : # если элемент равен прошлому и позапрошлому 
            x += 3 # увеличиваем число удаленных элеметов
            List.remove(List[i]) # удаляем 1-й элемент
            List.remove(List[i + 1]) # 2-й элемент
            List.remove(List[i - 1]) # 3-й элемент
except : # если ошибка то 
    print(f'удалено {x} элементов') # выводим данные об удаление
    print(List) # выводим конечный список
```

Comment: Зачем так долго?

Comment: @ПИТОНИСТверсия-3-8 может нужно пересесть на обновленную версию python ? и не быть таким токсичным

Comment: Python 3-8. Неправильно сказал: код-то работает, но результат неверный - удаляет, например, только 3 символа, а не 6

Comment: @ПИТОНИСТверсия-3-8 , странно при выполнении моего и вашего кода выходит одинаковый результат, за исключением `print(f'Остался список {a}, удалено {s} символов.')` , у меня это ` print(f'удалено {x} элементов') 
    print(List)`

Comment: Твой код хорош, огромное спасибо что приделил мне время, но код который я отметил сверху меньший. Хотя твой полностью понятный, из за комментариев. Все же я отметил его, и я не могу отметить 2 ответа. Сори 